# Resharper - Use only Inspection and Nothing Else at All in the Package

Tags: resharper

I have been evaluating Resharper and have heard how great it is. I agree that its code inspection is great, but I have to seriously disagree with the greatness of most other features.

All of the warts it adds to Visual Studio are killing my productivity. It has eaten Visual Studio's shortcut keys even though I told it not to, and even when I remap "Find All References" to Visual Studio, Resharper still coopts it.

We would like to be able to use the Code Inspection functionality and *absolutely* nothing else. Is this possible through documented or undocumented methods?

Comment: Did you try setting ReSharper Keyboard Shortcuts to None and resetting Visual Studio keyboard bindings?

Comment: I tried both of those, but it still owns my shortcuts. :(

Comment: Then you should try our support, see http://www.jetbrains.com/support/resharper/

Answer (score 0):

If problem only in keyboard shortcuts, you can change Keyboard scheme to Visual Studio. Go to menu `Resharper -> Options -> Keyboard and Menus`. Check `Visual Studio` Keyboard scheme at right part of window and apply it.